# Property does not exist in this type

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Im new to TypeScript and I'm facing righ now some of 'type' problems.
I tried to find similiar problems but they couldnt have helped me.

My webpack returned 3 errors:

1. `TS2339: Property 'current_category' does not exist on type '{ filterByCategory: (array: any) => any; }'`.
2. `TS2339: Property 'filterByCategory' does not exist on type '{ filteredProducts: () =>` any; }'.
3. `TS2339:` `Property 'services' does not exist on type '{ filteredProducts: () => any; }'`.

My code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";
import {ref} from "vue";
import type {WP_REST_API_Posts} from 'wp-types';

declare var wpFrontendLocalizer: any;

export default {
  name: 'HomePage',
  components: {},
  
  methods: {
    filterByCategory: function(array: any){
      return array.filter((service: any) => service.type == this.current_category) ;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      current_category:"xxx",
      services:[
        
      ]
    }
  },
  computed:{
    filteredProducts: function(){
      return this.filterByCategory(this.services);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens because your component's `current_category`, `filterByCategory` function and `services` isn't recognized by TypeScript. These functions can be added by using the `interface`. You need to define these types first like this.

```js
interface MyComponent {
  current_category: string;
  filterByCategory(array: any): any;
  services: any[];
  filteredProducts(): any;
}

export default {
  name: 'HomePage',
  components: {},
  methods: {
    filterByCategory(array: any) {
      return array.filter((service: any) => service.type == this.current_category);
    }
  },
  data(): MyComponent {
    return {
      current_category: "xxx",
      services: [],
      filteredProducts() {
        return this.filterByCategory(this.services);
      }
    };
  },
  mounted() {},
};
```